# How can i use the outer function?

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a list (`**t** - approximate nearest neighbors` )  as argument and computes `the similarity` between two vectors :

[image]

e.g :

- For `the list f2` , the similarity between `f2[[6]]`  &  `f2[[7]]` is : 3/4=0.75
- The number of commun elements between `the rows/vectors` 6 and 7 is `intersect(6,7)=3`, commun elements are (3,4,5) ,  where `**t** = 4`.
- n = 7.

I developped the similarity function as follow :

```
similarity<-function(p,q,mat,t){
  if(is.list(mat)){
    mat=list.as.matrix(mat, byrow=TRUE )
    p=mat[p,]
    q=mat[q,]
    p=p[!is.na(p)]
    q=q[!is.na(q)]
    return(length(intersect(p,q))/t)
  }

  if (p==q) return(0) 
  }
```

where : `p & q` are vectors of ***length = t*** , `mat` is a list that represent the `t-approximate nearest neighbors matrix`.

- I know that the similarity matrix is `symmetric` :

***similarity ( p , q , mat , t) = similarity ( q , p , mat , t)***

So the code of similarity matrix works as follow :

```
  similarity_matrix<-function(tann_matr,n,t){

  similarity_matr=matrix(data=NA,nrow=n,ncol=n)

  for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
     similarity_matr[i,j]=similarity(i,j,tann_matr,t)
    }   
  }
  diag(similarity_matr)=0
  return(similarity_matr)
}
```

***Question :***

I tried to change this function because of time-complexity , we just need to fill **upper-part** of the matrix. I guess that `outer function` could be a good solution , i tried :

```
similarity_matrix<-function(tann_matr,n,t){

  n1=n
  row=1:n1
  col=1:n1
  similarity_matr=matrix(data=NA,nrow=n1,ncol=n1)
  fun <- function(i,j,arg_1=tann_matr,arg_2=t) similarity(i,j,arg_1,arg_2)
  return(outer(col,row,FUN=fun))
}
```

The solution doesn't work as excpected , the output is different in that alternative.

I wish it's clear , Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** It might be fast enough even without doing anything more if you vectorize it.

```
denom <-  lengths(f2)[1]  # 4
f2na <- lapply(f2, na.omit)
len <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y))
m <- outer(f2na, f2na, Vectorize(len)) / denom
diag(m) <- 0
```

giving:

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[2,]    0    0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[3,]    0    0 0.00 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
[4,]    0    0 0.75 0.00 0.75 0.75 0.75
[5,]    0    0 0.75 0.75 0.00 0.75 0.75
[6,]    0    0 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.00 0.75
[7,]    0    0 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.00
```

**2)**  Another possibility is to encode each component of f2 into a 0/1 vector and then take the crossprod of that:

```
mx <- max(unlist(f2), na.rm = TRUE) # 7
M <- crossprod(sapply(f2, tabulate, mx)) / denom
diag(M) <- 0

identical(m, M)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
f2 <- list(structure(c(2, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(1L, 4L)), structure(c(1, 
NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(1L, 4L)), structure(4:7, .Dim = c(1L, 4L
)), structure(c(3, 5, 6, 7), .Dim = c(1L, 4L)), structure(c(3L, 
4L, 6L, 7L), .Dim = c(1L, 4L)), structure(c(3, 4, 5, 7), .Dim = c(1L, 
4L)), structure(3:6, .Dim = c(1L, 4L)))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot G. Grothendieck , did the solution exploit the fact that the matrix is symmetric ?

Comment: No but you may not need to.

Comment: G. Grothendieck Thanks a lot again.